# Deploy Spring War locally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, port

How can I deploy my Spring Boot microservice on my ubuntu server, so that only the localhost can access it.
For example I got a user-service : localhost:8888.
I dont want to this to be accessible globaly. Only the localhost should be able to do that.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set server.address to localhost then your app is not accessible from outside.

Set the following in the application.properties

server.address=127.0.0.1